# Lightbox Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I'm making my first website and I'm trying to make my own lightbox. Till now, only the first pic can be visible in the modal. Although the ID and the source move when I click, the modal doesn't open. Here my JS code :

```
var modal = document.getElementById('simple-modal');
var modalBtn = document.getElementById('img-link');
var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('close-modal')[0];
const current = document.querySelector('#current');
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.imgs img');

modalBtn.addEventListener('click', openModal);
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);
imgs.forEach(img => img.addEventListener('click', imgClick));

$('.imgs img').click(function() {

    $('#img-link').removeAttr('id');  

    $(this).attr('id', 'img-link');

    return false;
});

function openModal(e) {
    if (e.target == modalBtn) {
        modal.style.display = 'flex';
    }
}

function imgClick(e) {
    current.src = e.target.src;
}

function closeModal() {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
}

function outsideClick(e) {
    if(e.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Edit, as resquested, here my HTML :

HTML

```
<div class="imgs">
    <img id="img-link" src="../img/pizza-it.png" alt="">
    <img src="../img/mv-logo.png" alt="">
    <img src="../img/kanari-logo.png" alt="">
    <img src="../img/kanari-carte.png" alt="">
</div>

<div id="simple-modal" class="gallery-modal">

    <div class="close-modal">
        <span>&times;</span>
    </div>

    <div id="arrow-prev" class="arrow"></div>

    <div class="modal-box">
        <img src="" id="current">
    </div>

    <div id="arrow-next" class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code has jQuery in it, but you've specified "vanilla JS with no frameworks".

Comment: maybe some html to go along with this javascript would make this easier to debug

Comment: I think the poster means "no libraries" instead of "no frameworks".

Comment: And the open button?

Comment: Are you adding your JavaScript before or after the HTML is rendered? In other words, are you adding the JS to the head or at the very bottom of your HTML file?

Comment: JS file is at the end of the HTML

Comment: You are binding the click event only once to the id="img-link" upon page load, but when you click on the image, you are shifting the id to the next image. The click event hasn't been attached to the next image because you only have one image with id="img-link" at the start. You can try binding the click event to modalBtn again after you have shifted the id to the next image element. Or you can try giving your images the same className and use the className as your query selector instead of shifting the id.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I try this : imgs.forEach(img => img.addEventListener('click', openModal));    Look like ot work in this way.